# Altium 365 - changing the default comment

Tags: schematics, components, altium, library, eda

Recently, our company decided to move to Altium 365 since we are starting a big project where multiple people will be working on a single project. We have a local library that is up to date and used trough the company.

For all our resistors and capacitors, the part comment is "=Value" so when placing the component we get this:

[image]

But, after migrating the library to the cloud, all the comments just got replaced with the Design Item ID, so we get this:

[image]

And I can't figure out how to change it. I looked at all the options available during the migration step, I tried to edit the components once they are in the library, but the Comment field just ist there to be edited. I tried to manually create part comment field, but Altium just puts out an error and states that its an "Reserved Parameter name".

I would like to keep all my Comment parameters from before the migration, but I would be happy if I just figured out how to change it for Resistors and Capacitors.

Comment: Altium has a forum. Put tool related questions there for better responses. https://live.altium.com/signin?prmGotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.live.altium.com%2F

Answer (score 1):

Use the Name attributem when editing component, it is the former Comment.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have the same "Problem". Altium requires the Manufacturer Partnumber (=full Ordercode) in the Comment field as it is used in the ActiveBom Doc to identify the item and search at all Distributors for the best Stock & price.

Based on one of the Altium Scripts examples I wrote one to hide the comment field and show the value field of all components in the Project.

Source:
[Altium Script examples](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/SCRT/Script+Examples+Reference)

```
\DelphiScript Scripts\SCH\UserDefinedParameters\UserDefinedCompParameters.PrjScr
```

ComponentParameters.pas:
This script demonstrates how to create, modify and delete user defined parameters for components in schematic designs of a hierarchical project.

ev. this Repo helps too: [GIT Repo with Altium Scripts](https://github.com/Altium-Designer-addons/scripts-libraries)

My sample code:

```
HideValue    : Boolean; 
HideComment  : Boolean;
HideTPValue  : Boolean;
SchModified  : Boolean;
```

...

```
SchModified := false;
HideValue := false;
HideComment := true;
HideTPValue := true;

// Hide/Show value parameter 
if (UpperCase(Parameter.Name) = UpperCase('VALUE')) then
begin
    // Value of Testpoint shall be treated extra
    if (UpperCase(Parameter.Text) = UpperCase('Testpoint')) then
    begin
        Parameter.IsHidden := HideTPValue;
        SchModified := true;
    end;
    end
    // NO ; here after end as an else follows
    else if (Parameter.IsHidden <> HideValue) then
    begin 
        Parameter.IsHidden :=  HideValue;
        SchModified := true;
    end;
end;
```

...
Mark the file as Dirty:

```
if (SchModified = true) then
begin
    // Mark document as modified
    Document.Modified := True;
    SchModified := false;
end;
finally
   SchDocument.SchIterator_Destroy(Iterator);
```

...